# Are $|\arg(z-k)|=\pi/2$ and $\text{Re}(z)=k$ the same equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Do $|\arg(z-k)|=\pi/2$ and $\text{Re}(z)=k$ represent the same equation $x=k$?   (Where $k$ is a purely real number)

I encountered these as the options to a multiple choice question. I believe they are same but, only one of them is the answer, meaning they are different.

How do they differ geometrically?

Comment: The first equation does not include the point $z=k$ whereas the second does. So they are not the same equation.

Comment: @complexmanifold - that is not what $\arg(z-k)$ means.

Comment: The first equation is not valid as $\arg(z)$ is a multivalued function, but it is being set equal to a single value. I've never once seen $\arg(z)$ defined to exclude the imaginary axis: its branch cuts are on the negative real line typically. If the answers below are correct I'd be very annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Very subtle here.  It looks like they are both the same line -- but at $z=k$ itself $arg (z-k)$ is undefined with $x-k=0$.  Thus $|arg (z-k)|=\pi/2$ is missing that one point.

Comment: It looks like that was the professor was looking for, but $\arg(z)$ should be defined at $\pi/2$. The definition of $\arg(z)$ is the angle connecting the positive real axis to the line passing through the point $z$ and the origin. The argument can be computed via $\arctan(z)$ but that is not the definition of $\arg(z)$. Perhaps my understanding is wrong, but I also see no benefit to choosing a definition which is unnecessarily undefined at points in its domain.